# Determine if a message is too long to embed in an image

Tags: c, steganography, ppm

I created a program that embeds a message in a PPM file by messing with the last bit in each byte in the file. The problem I have right now is that I don't know if I am checking if a message is too long or not correctly. Here's what I've got so far:

```
int hide_message(const char *input_file_name, const char *message, const char *output_file_name)
{
    unsigned char * data;
    int n;
    int width;
    int height;
    int max_color;

    //n = 3 * width * height;
    int code = load_ppm_image(input_file_name, &data, &n, &width, &height, &max_color);

    if (code)
    {
        // return the appropriate error message if the image doesn't load correctly
        return code;
    }

    int len_message;
    int count = 0;
    unsigned char letter;

    // get the length of the message to be hidden
    len_message = (int)strlen(message);


    if (len_message > n/3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "The message is longer than the image can support\n");
        return 4;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < len_message; j++)
    {

        letter = message[j];
        int mask = 0x80;

        // loop through each byte
        for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
        {
            if((letter & mask) == 0)
            {
                //set right most bit to 0
                data[count] = 0xfe & data[count];
            }
            else
            {
                //set right most bit to 1
                data[count] = 0x01 | data[count];
            }
            // shift the mask
            mask = mask>>1 ;
            count++;
        }
    }
    // create the null character at the end of the message (00000000)
    for(int b = 0; b < 8; b++){
        data[count] = 0xfe & data[count];
        count++;
    }

    // write a new image file with the message hidden in it
     int code2 = write_ppm_image(output_file_name, data, n, width, height, max_color);

    if (code2)
    {
        // return the appropriate error message if the image doesn't load correctly
        return code2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So I'm checking to see if the length of the message (len_message) is longer that n/3, which is the same thing as width*height. Does that seem correct?

Comment: What makes you think your check is incorrect?

Comment: 8 bits in a byte! `if (len_message > n/3)` checks to see if the entire length of the message is longer than the length * width. Well let's say the length is 10 and width is 10. If we have a message of 10 characters, our entire binary is going to be 80 1's and 0's long. Change `len_message` to `len_message*8` or `strlen(message)*8`. You could also use each r,g, and b in the pixel which would greatly increase your size.

Comment: @user10984587: Don't use magic numbers! A `char` is not guaranteed to hold 8 bits. Use `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: When I've done work with ppm's you're usually taking the r, g, or b of a pixel (say `255,255,255`) and the ascii character `65 for A or 0100 0001`. So you take that initial ascii value, split it into its 8 bit binary representation. R becomes 250, G becomes 251, B become 250 and so on. In essence, OP is embedding an ascii message and it will always "technically" be 7 bits long, but for keeping this normal, you'd add the additional 0 on the front. In this case, the char would be guaranteed to hold 8 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The check you're currently doing is checking whether the message has more *bytes* than the image has pixels.  Because you're only using 1 bit per pixel to encode the message,  you need to check if the message has more *bits* than the message has pixels.

So you need to do this:

```
if (len_message*8 > n/3)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @dbush's remarks about checking the number of bits in your message, you appear not to be accounting for all the bytes available to you in the image.  Normal ("raw", P6-format) PPM images use three color samples per pixel, at either 8 or 16 bits per sample.  Thus, the image contains at least `3 * width * height` bytes of color data, and maybe as many as `6 * width * height`.

On the other hand, the point of steganophraphy is to make the presence of a hidden message difficult to detect.  In service to that objective, if you have a PPM with 16 bits per sample then you probably want to avoid modifying the more-significant bytes of the samples.  Or if you don't care about that, then you might as well use the whole low-order byte of each sample in that case.

Additionally, PPM files record the maximum possible value of any sample, which does not need to be the same as the maximum value of the underlying type.  It is possible for your technique to change the actual maximum value to be greater than the recorded maximum, and if you do not then change the maximum-value field as well then the inconsistency could be a tip-off that the file has been tampered with.

Furthermore, raw PPM format affords the possibility of multiple images of the same size in one file.  The file header does not express how many there are, so you have to look at the file size to tell.  You can use the bytes of every image in the file to hide your message.

Comment: 3 * width * height bits* not bytes.

Comment: @user10984587, no I'm saying the image color data comprise at least `3 * width * height` *bytes*.  How many bits of each of those is used to embed the message is a different question.  As I also wrote, one might want to use either more or fewer than one bit per byte to encode the message, depending on the circumstances.  I have clarified.

Comment: Alright. The "available to you" threw me off. Seemed like you were saying you had that many bytes to use so 3 * width * height characters are allowed to be embedded.